# Regrouping several application files into one

Tags: standards, file-handling

I am working on a C++ application which lets users work on projects.
Each project consists of several files that should not be known / edited manually by the user.

For that we currently use a folder structure to store the settings, the files created by the user in the app and some automatically generated files.

We would like to have only one file to ease the opening of the projects (selecting one file with a dedicated extension is easier than selecting a folder), to ease sharing the projects and also to limit the risks of users tampering with the files.

My first thought would be to do something like Excel (create an archive containing all the files and put a custom extension on it) but if I do so I don't know how I should access the file from my app (do I need to extract the archive in a temporary folder while my app is running for example, and if so what happens if the app crashes/the computer crashes/...).

Are there any standards/ known and validated ways of doing this kind of things ?

Comment: Q1: Does it make sense for your C++ application to load all the files at once at the beginning, and save them at once, for example, when the user presses a "Save" button? Or do you need to read and wrote individual files? Please clarify!

Comment: Q2: is changing the file format(s) an option? Or do you want to keep as much as possible from the current file formats inside the single file? Please clarify.

Comment: @DocBrown there are several steps in the project each step read some files and write other files. There is only one step done at a time so usually I load just the needed files at the beginning of a step and unload them at the end. I don't need to open all the files at the start of the program.

Changing the file format might be an option but I don't really see why doing this would change something...

Comment: Q3: Wouldn't be easier to define a descriptor? Say an XML or Json (or make your own format) per project, holding the reference to all the files involved? That's your meta-project file. An index or map.

Comment: ... because if you can change the file format, you could use a lightweight file-based database system like SQLite. That gives you the ergonomics of keeping everything in one file with the power of reading and writing arbitrary parts of it in a random-access manner, without corrupting your data in case of an application crash. If there is some kind of standard, then this.

Comment: @Laiv One of the Issue I have with that is that I would prefer to obfuscate (at least a little bit) the files / architecture. I know that security through obscurity is not a good thing but sometimes we have user who, instead of calling support when they have an issue, modify the files by hand (which breaks everything) and then call support. I think hiding just a bit the files might help even if it's not a perfect solution.

Comment: @DocBrown my issue with using SQLite is first that I will need to reformat some data (and for some of the project parts I have a lots of key-value maps which might be cumbersome to store in a DB). And also with a zip file, when the user creates a new project I know I can easily create a zip file, I dont know how easy (or hard) it can be to create a SQLite file and  populate the schema in the DB before using it.

Comment: If you don't want to change most of your existing file formats, you could use a BLOB record for each file inside the SQLite DB, then you keep the ability to read and write the data in the same granularity as you do today. And creating a new SQlite file  with the right schema is trivial: prepare an "empty" SQLite database file which contains only the schema plus any standard value tables, then simply copy that file.

Comment: @f222 Rather than writing "strings" in a specific format (csv, tsv, json, xml, etc) just write all the bytes. Make binaries :-). If possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison with Excel (and many other apps which do the same thing) is spot on.

ZIP archives can be manipulated from most programming languages relatively easily. You don't need to extract files into temporary folders but only need to change your app to read from and write to ZIP streams (plus some additional archive handling code to open/close the archive when appropriate). A quick internet search turned up https://github.com/Zipios/Zipios as a possible C++ library which even supports transparent handling of archive and regular files (note I did not test whether this is suitable for your purpose and what others exist, but it may be a starting point for your own search).

Unpacking into a temp file would only be necessary when an archive member must be used in a random access fashion, as I think the streams provided by the library are sequential.

Comment: Well, if there's concurrency, you might need to lock the files. For the sake of your sanity, you will create a temporal file and work on it and synchronize changes with the main data source (zip). If files are small enough, you can load as many streams into memory as you can, but if files are large (say gigabytes) it could be too much.